# Can't Send Texts to Some Phones unless Internet Turned on on my Pixel 5

Tags: sms, google-pixel

I have a Google Pixel 5 phone, am running Android 13, and use Verizon as my carrier. I'm trying to use the internet less so I usually keep my internet off, including turning off my data and wifi connections.

I've noticed that when my internet is turned off I can't send texts to some people until I turn my internet back on. The send text message button on my phone is grayed out when trying to text some people until I turn the internet back on. I can send text messages to some people with the internet turned off, including to some iPhone users.

**Is this issue most likely caused by trying to send texts to a person's iPhone and they have iMessage turned on?**

I'm aware that if an iPhone user turns on iMessage then they must keep their internet connection on or they can't send texts from their phone.

Comment: Which messaging app are you using?

Comment: Andrew T. I'm using the default Android Text messaging app called "Messages" on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

The **internet** of most phones usually will include cell connections, too. If your trying to email other users on Iphone, **it uses a standalone service specific to apple and its cell network** thus not requiring verizon's cell service hece apples own cell service can process the request at much higher speeds. But if whom you are sending to isn't on apple's own network or icloud, **It cant use the apple servers because they are not built to communicate with other clients directly and has to use another server which requires a cell connection / wifi to connect with those client servers**

Comment: I meant to say that I turn 2 things off on my cell phone most of the time:  
1. Mobile data. 
2. Wi-fi. 

Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: If this is the case, simply DONT turn off mobile data if you want to text non-iphone users not over wifi